# How to draw on jPanel with JOgl

Tags: netbeans, jogl

I use JOGL in Netbeans 8.0.2. I want to draw the classic colored triangle on a panel and also to select number of sides of the geometrical figure (4, 5 sides) using the Netbeans palette controls but I have no idea how.The panel is on the frame. So far my code is :

Class PanelGL:

```
package panelgl;

import com.jogamp.opengl.*;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.WindowAdapter;
import com.jogamp.newt.event.WindowEvent;
import com.jogamp.newt.opengl.GLWindow;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLCanvas;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

 public class PanelGL implements GLEventListener{

       public static void main(String[] args) {
             final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get( GLProfile.GL2 ); 
             GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);

             final GLJPanel glpanel = new GLJPanel( capabilities ); 
             PanelGL triangle = new PanelGL(); 
             glpanel.addGLEventListener( triangle ); 
             glpanel.setSize( 400, 400 );   

             final GLFrame frame = new GLFrame ("Colored Triangle"); 

             frame.getContentPane().add( glpanel ); 
             frame.setSize( frame.getContentPane().getPreferredSize()); 
             frame.setVisible( true ); 
        }

        @Override
       public void init(GLAutoDrawable glad) {    }

        @Override
        public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glad) {    }

       @Override
       public void display(GLAutoDrawable glad) {    
              final GL2 gl = glad.getGL().getGL2(); 
              gl.glBegin( GL2.GL_TRIANGLES );  
              gl.glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );   // Red 
              gl.glVertex3f( 0.5f,0.7f,0.0f );    // Top 
              gl.glColor3f( 0.0f,1.0f,0.0f );     // green 
              gl.glVertex3f( -0.2f,-0.50f,0.0f ); // Bottom Left 
             gl.glColor3f( 0.0f,0.0f,1.0f );     // blue 
             gl.glVertex3f( 0.5f,-0.5f,0.0f );   // Bottom Right 

            gl.glEnd();    
         }

    @Override
   public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glad, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {    }

}
```

Class GLFrame

```
     public class GLFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

       public GLFrame(String title) {
          this.setTitle(title);
          initComponents();
       }

           private javax.swing.JPanel glPanel;
    }
```

glPanel is add via palette.

I want that the drawing to be on this specifically panel (glPanel).

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that extends GLJPanel instead of  GLEventListener. You would  still use the GLEventListener internally. After you have compiled the class you can right click it in the Projects window for the pop-up menu to select `Tools` -> `Add To Palette ...` to add it to the palette. To Create a property that will be editable just use the normal bean pattern with getter and setter or use `Alt-Insert` and then select `Add Property` to add the variable and getter and setter.

eg..

```
import com.jogamp.opengl.GL2;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLAutoDrawable;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLCapabilities;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLEventListener;
import com.jogamp.opengl.GLProfile;
import com.jogamp.opengl.awt.GLJPanel;
import java.awt.Dimension;


public class MyJOGLFigure extends GLJPanel {

    public MyJOGLFigure() {
        this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));
        final GLProfile profile = GLProfile.get(GLProfile.GL2);
        GLCapabilities capabilities = new GLCapabilities(profile);
        this.addGLEventListener(new GLEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void init(GLAutoDrawable glad) {

            }

            @Override
            public void dispose(GLAutoDrawable glad) {

            }

            @Override
            public void display(GLAutoDrawable glad) {
                System.out.println("numberOfSides = " + numberOfSides);
                final GL2 gl = glad.getGL().getGL2();
                gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_TRIANGLES);
                gl.glColor3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);   // Red 
                gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, 0.7f, 0.0f);    // Top 
                gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);     // green 
                gl.glVertex3f(-0.2f, -0.50f, 0.0f); // Bottom Left 
                gl.glColor3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);     // blue 
                gl.glVertex3f(0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f);   // Bottom Right 

                gl.glEnd();
            }

            @Override
            public void reshape(GLAutoDrawable glad, int i, int i1, int i2, int i3) {

            }
        });
    }

   // Example editable property.
   private int numberOfSides = 3;

    /**
     * Get the value of numberOfSides
     *
     * @return the value of numberOfSides
     */
    public int getNumberOfSides() {
        return numberOfSides;
    }

    /**
     * Set the value of numberOfSides
     *
     * @param numberOfSides new value of numberOfSides
     */
    public void setNumberOfSides(int numberOfSides) {
        this.numberOfSides = numberOfSides;
    }
}
```

After you have dragged the MyJoglFigure from the palette to the JFrame design, you can find and edit the numberOfSides property. NOTE that I only print it, i didn't actually use it to change the drawing. ( exercise for the reader ? )